# WPF/Designer: ItemContainerStyle RadioButton as ToggleButton. Works when in runtime but fails in designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-designer

I have a ItemsControl with an ItemContainerStyle based on ToggleButton.
This works just fine at runetime, but it casts an error in the designer. (So I have to comment it out if i want to use the designer)
I populate this with code behind. Using RadioButtons.

**InvalidOperationException: A style intended for type 'RadioButton' cannot be applied to type 'ContentPresenter'.**

Iv lived with this for along time now, but its time to see if there is a solution!

Any ideas how to work around this?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="BrushButtons"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="3"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical" />

    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="70" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Kind Regards.

Comment: The items container of an ItemsControl is a ContentPresenter, so your ItemContainerStyle should target ContentPresenter. Instead of populating the control with RadioButtons in code behind, you should define an ItemTemplate with a RadioButton.

Comment: Okey, Thank you for your response. Will try to rewrite it.